# jquery check if starts with for a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following in my .delegate:
link_id is the id of the link.
I need to next say if that id started with RPwd then do something.
Why doesn't ^= work in this case?

```
    var link_id = $(this).attr('id');  //capture the id of the clicked link
    if (link_id ^= "RPwd") {
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery 1.7+ you should be using `.prop` instead of `.attr` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The starts with `^=` selector is a jQuery object selector.  You're doing a string comparison, and can therefore use `indexOf()`

```
if (link_id.indexOf("RPwd") === 0) {
   // Match
}
```

Comment: Why === and not ==? what are the differences?

Comment: @gdoron: `===` compares type as well as value, `==` just compares value.  `0 == '0'` is `true`, but `0 === '0'` is `false`.

Comment: @Rocket, Which is more efficient?

Comment: @gdoron: Neither is more "efficient", but I suggest using `===`.

Comment: @gdoron It isn't about efficient it is about correctness. Does it really matter if you get the wrong answer faster?

Comment: @JohnFx: It depends on what you're doing.  Do you want `'10'` to equal `10`?

Comment: @Rocket That was kind of my point. The efficiency doesn't matter if whichever he picks doesn't have the correct behavior. That's all I meant.

Comment: @JohnFx: Ah, ok, I get ya :-)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know `^=` is not an operator in javascript. That could be your problem.

I think you are looking for

```
if ($(this).is('[id^="RPwd"]')) {
}
```

Comment: `link_id` here is a string.  You'd want `$(this).is('[id^="RPwd"]')`.